# Pandas: filtering for unique strings in 2 columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bioinformatics

I've got two DataFrames, as follows:

```
Interactor 1    Interactor 2   Interaction Type
Q99459          Q14204         MI:0914(association)
Q96G01          Q14203         MI:0914(association)
P01106          Q9H0S4         MI:0914(association)
Q9HAU4          P0CG47         MI:0414(enzymatic reaction)
O95786          Q14790         MI:0915(physical association)
... (90000 rows)
```

and

```
Gene    UniProt ID
ABI1    Q8IZP0
ABL1    P00519
AKT1    P31749
AP2A1   O95782
AP2B1   P63010
... (244 rows)
```

What I want to do is this:

1. Remove any rows where the `Interaction Type` column in `df1` differs from a set of partial strings
2. Remove any rows where `Interactor 1` is the same as `Interactor 2`
3. Remove any rows where either of `Interactor 1` or `Interactor 2` ISN'T in `df2`'s `UniProt ID` column
4. Remove any duplicated rows
5. (Problem here) Remove the rows where a mirrored interaction is found, but keep one

The last one is the crux of the problem, really; I'll try to explain what I mean by it. An interaction pair is the two `Interactor` columns. Removing duplicate interaction pairs (4) is easy, but not the mirrored versions. For example, a mirrored interaction pair would look like this:

```
Interactor 1     Interactor 2
Q123             Q456
Q456             Q123
```

These, I don't want. Or, rather, I want just ONE of them, but it doesn't matter which. How would I do this? I've got the following code, which does points (1) through (4) easily enough, but I can't figure out how to do (5)...

```
# Read data
input_file = 'Interaction lists/PrimesDB PPI.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(input_file, sheetname='Sheet 1')
data = data[['Interactor 1', 'Interactor 2', 'Interaction Type']]

# Filter: interaction types
data = data[data['Interaction Type'].str.contains(
    'MI:0407|MI:0915|MI:0203|MI:0217')]

# Filter: self-interactions
data = data[data['Interactor 1'] != data['Interactor 2']]

# Filter: included genes
genes = pd.read_excel('Interaction lists/PrimesDB PPI (filtered).xlsx',
    sheetname='Gene list')
data = data[data['Interactor 1'].isin(genes['UniProt ID'])]
data = data[data['Interactor 2'].isin(genes['UniProt ID'])]

# Filter: unique interactions
unique = data.drop_duplicates(cols=['Interactor 1', 'Interactor 2')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your fifth item, removing duplicate pairs, you can try something like the following using the **select** method on *DataFrame*.  It returns a *DataFrame* containing the row you want to remove (assuming the duplicates you want to remove are where "interactor 2" is lexicographically greater than "interactor 1"

### Filter 1

```
#find duplicate pairs
filter = df.select(lambda x: (
                       (df['Interactor 2'] > df['Interactor 1']) &
                       (df['Interactor 2'] == df['Interactor 1'].loc[x]) & 
                       (df['Interactor 1'] == df['Interactor 2'].loc[x])
                   ).any())
#remove duplicate pairs
df.drop(filter.index, inplace=True)
```

You'll get better performance it you iterate over a smaller collection, and perform less work on each row, so moving the first comparison out of the loop will improve performance:

### Filter 2

```
#find duplicate pairs
filter = (df['Interactor 2'] > df['Interactor 1']).select(lambda x: (
                       (df['Interactor 2'] == df['Interactor 1'].loc[x]) & 
                       (df['Interactor 1'] == df['Interactor 2'].loc[x])
                   ).any())
#remove duplicate pairs
df.drop(filter.index, inplace=True)
```

To test, I'm using [this datasource](http://biodev.extra.cea.fr/interoporc/files/study4932/srcInteractionsUsed.txt).

```
import pandas as pd
url = "http://biodev.extra.cea.fr/interoporc/files/study4932/srcInteractionsUsed.txt"
i1, i2 = 'ProteinAcA', 'ProteinAcB'
df1 = pd.read_table(url)  #1470 x 7 rows
df2 = df1.ix[:10].copy(deep=True) #11 x 7 rows
df2[i1] = df1.ix[:10][i2]
df2[i2] = df1.ix[:10][i1]
df2.index = range(1481,1492) 
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]) #1481 x 7 rows
filter = df[df[i1] > df[i2]].select(lambda x: (
                           (df[i2] == df[i1].loc[x]) & 
                           (df[i1] == df[i2].loc[x])).any() )
```

or

```
def FilterMirroredDuplicates(dataFrame, col1, col2):
    df = dataFrame[dataFrame[col1] > dataFrame[col2]]
    return df.select(lambda x: ((dataFrame[col2] == df[col1].loc[x]) & (dataFrame[col1] == df[col2].loc[x])).any()) 
filter = FilteredMirrorDuplicates(df, i1, i2)  #11 x 7 rows
```

The function **FilterMirroredDuplicates** does the same as the **select** statement above it.  Working on this, I did find that *Filter 2* above doesn't generate the appropriate set of indices to drop.  Either the statement or function above should solve your problem.

Keep in mind that using **select** is **O**(n^2).  But I can't think of any better means to perform this check.

Comment: Weird. Firstly, using those two different codes yields different results, and secondly, they don't correspond to semi-manual results I have as a control... The first version you gave yields around 1300 final interaction pairs, while the second one around 600, whereas the correct number is around 800. Ideas?

Comment: Try replacing `ix` with `loc` in either example.  See [Indexing and Selecting Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) for the difference between `loc`, `iloc`, and `ix`, as the last can be interpreted as either an index label, or positional.

Comment: I get different numbers that with `ix`, but still wrong ones =/

Comment: I tried the algorithm on [this datasource](http://biodev.extra.cea.fr/interoporc/files/study4932/srcInteractionsUsed.txt), and didn't find any mirrored pairs, so massaged the data by concatenating the source with the first 10 rows having their protein columns swapped, and ran the select statement, and it detected the pairs, so the algorithm does work.  I'll writeup my test in the answer so you can verify.

Comment: That fixed the numbers somewhat, but not totally. I tried with your dataset and of course it worked, so I figured it had to be something I did/didn't do. After a while I figured out that I didn't remove some duplicates in step (4) that should be removed, due to considering the entire row rather than just the two interactor columns (edited code in original post to reflect). So now it works great, thanks for the help!